# can I specify each receiver can receive its own data in ssrs subscription data driven

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to send only the receiver content report for in the To based on its content and filtered by its email using data-driven SSRS subscription

Ex: I have an attendance report and I would like to send this report to all employees but each employee should receive it's copy report with his data Can I do this with SSRS data-driven.

Comment: yes. there are plenty of examples out there. Here's the first I found https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e7a5b2f-a3dd-4318-be41-689f2288cf07/ssrsdata-driven-subscription-email-report-content-based-on-conditionuser

Comment: what you describe is exactly what data driven subscription is meant to do. Short answer to your questions - Yes you can.